# C# .NET4.5.1 Regex strange?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I'm reading text files that has decimal numbers in them. They can be made in "any" Culture so the decimal point may be different to the current culture.

So I use a regex to replace all different CurrencyDecimalSeparators with the current.

I'm using this code

```
string output = Regex.Replace(inValue, @"[\.\?,;/-]", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
```

e.g. 1.25 -> 1,25 (I'm in Sweden)

Now to my question: When I first tried this I was using this regexp **@"[\.,;/-\?]"** which didn't work. All characters where replaced with the current separator.

e.g. 1.25 -> ,,,,

Why?

// Anders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of `/-\?`. This is a character range of `/` to `?` (the `?` is being escaped).

This range covers:

```
/ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
```

If you see a [unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/)

[image]

Comment: So it's the - that makes it a range. So it can be solved by escaping the - like \-

Comment: @Andis59: Or by using `-` as the first or last character in the group.